# How to deploy both Spring boot and angular project separately on apache tomcat

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, deployment

I have created Spring boot application and Angular project (Angular 1) separately. In my local i am using npm to server the client app and it calls my back end app services. I am using Embedded tomcat in spring boot application.

Now i want to host my application in server. How do i do that?
Can i have embedded tomcat and build as jar or should i have to install standalone tomcat in the server and deploy my application as war?

How to configure my client code for example, in godaddy i have given ip xx.xx.xx.xx to www.xyz.com. The ip address is my production cloud server. How to redirect to angular application and that application calls server exposed apis.

I cannot have single application that has client code. I should do with two different application only. Please help me deploying this in best way. If embedded tomcat doesnt help then i can install standalone tomcat in server and and build my app as war and deploy it.

Comment: You can deploy both client and server in the same web server such as Tomcat. In order to deploy client, you can generate the static files from Angular and copy to the tomcat web-app folder. Eventually you would like to automate this task.

Comment: @PrabinPaudel how to configure virtual hosts? I have 2 applications in webapp folder in tomcat one is backend project and other one is 
frontend project. If i hit www.xyz.com from browser, tomcat should serve frontend angular project. Can you help in this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The current best practice would be to embed the servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, other) into the artifact and build a fat JAR. The main advantage is a simplified deployment process: it's enough to push the far JAR into environment and execute it. Unlike the usual servlet container with WAR deployment model the embedded approach doesn't have to deal with additional configuration layers e.g. thread pools or data sources shared between different WARs.

One example of how to build a far JAR with embedded servlet container is `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency with [`spring-boot-maven-plugin:repackage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) goal. In this setup to build a fat JAR it's enough to run `mvn clean package repackage`.

If you are developing locally your web client code most likely will face issues with the same-origin policy. You most likely will need a CORS filter, however it's [provided by Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter_and_HttpServletRequest_attributes).